# php - get the date of next tuesday and wednesday for the next 3 weeks

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I have a drupal 7 website and I need to create a select list with the dates of the next tues and thursday for the next 3 weeks (so 6 dates in total). It needs to be in php mode

Comment: Have you tried anything? Searched in the PHP doc but don't know how to use...?

Comment: Sounds great! How's it going?

Comment: I would start with DateTime objects: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php If you have issues, please let us known specifically what you've tried or don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

"get the date of next tuesday and wednesday for the next 3 weeks"

Assuming this is the question:

`strtotime("next Tuesday");
strtotime("next Tuesday +1 week");
strtotime("next Tuesday +2 weeks");`
etc...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: you can do what @Joseph suggested and put it in your drupal php file and have it drop down select list.